# How can I control print level in pyomo with Cplex

Tags: cplex, pyomo

I want to get more information from cplex printed results. What should I do in pyomo? Is there a parameter to control that? thanks!

Comment: Which kind of information are you trying to access?

Comment: I want to know more about the process information. I already know what to do. Thank you!